# How to update an existing code repository with an updated solution? Git Hub

Tags: git, github

I recently created a repository on GitHub to host my college projects but I'm not sure how to replace my original source code with my new finished solution.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this in the command line? Below is how I uploaded the initial solution which I want to update.

```
cd C:\Users\Nrian Varley\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects

\KinectKickboxingBVversion1

git init

git add KinectKickboxingBVversion1

git commit -m "adding files". 

git remote add originNew 

https://github.com/NrianJVarley/College_Kinect_Project.git

git push originNew master
```

Comment: with `git push` you can upload changes after you have commited them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your git commands are just fine.  That will update all existing sources.

If you are receiving an issue, something around the lines of "error ref spec remote does not exist" or something - it's because you spelled your name wrong in the remote!

```
$ git remote add originNew https://github.com/BrianJVarley/College_Kinect_Project.git
```

You spelled Brian, `Nrian`

If you see that it still says `"changes to be committed: ./KinectKickboxingBVversion1"` then it might have something to do with recursion.  Try a:

```
$ git add -A KinectKickboxingBVversion1
```

Comment: Okay Ill try my existing code now I didn't run it a second time yet,also I just changed the name for the purpose of asking the question.